# The conditional probability in subset situation

Tags: probability

If $A$ $\subset$ $B$,and $P(A)=\frac{1}{4}$,$P(B)=\frac{1}{3}$,then what is $P(B|A)$?

First,i think if  $A$ $\subset$ $B$ means $B$ is one of part of $A$,so  $P(B\cap A)$ should be equal $P(B)$,but i use this to calculate this probability,it will be bigger than $1$,so i am wrong obviously.

Comment: "$A$ $\subset$ $B$ means $B$ is one of part of $A$" ?? Well... no.

Answer (score 3):

If $A \subset B$, then $B \cap A=A$ !

Comment: oh ! i misunderstand that  $A \subset B$

Answer (score 1):

*it will be one always*
As it's been asked to find probability of B given event A has occurred already.....
But A is subset of B! A can't happen prior happening of B.
Mathematically also...
P(B/A)=P(A)/P(A)=1.

Comment: oh! i misunderstand about  $A \subset B$

Comment: Yeah ! It happens sometimes....☺